# Read MS Access .mdb database using Ruby on Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, ms-access

Is there any way to query tables from a Microsoft Access .mdb database using Ruby on a Linux platform?

I would like to read directly, not convert to Mysql then read. In fact, being more specific, I would like to query the tables i.e. add filters etc

Comment: This is basically a "ask for recommendations" question (which will likely get it closed) but you probably need some combination of `unixODBC` plus an ODBC library on the Ruby side.

Comment: You might be able to use JRuby along with the UCanAccess JDBC driver.

Comment: @Joe note that you will need to have a Linux ODBC driver for Access when going for that. There is one available with [MDBTools](https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools), but UCanAccess might be a better solution.